# switch Observable stream and grab subscription each next

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have an Observable listening to the URL and I am `switch`ing it to a `getRows()` which returns an Observable pulling data back from the API with the URL parameters. I want to be able get a Subscription reference for every emit that `getRows()` does. This is to show a loading indicator on the UI.

The current code:

```
this.tableSource = this.urlParamService.getParameterGroup(this.parameterPrefix)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .map(p => this.getRows(p))
    .switch()
    .share();
```

And then explicitly when I have changed the parameters I have been calling:

```
this.tableLoad = this.tableSource.take(1).subscribe((r) => this.rows = this.parseRows(r));
```

But I want to enable the component to update when external entities manipulate the URL and so I should be subscribing instead of sharing `tableSource`, so how can I get a Subscription everytime I call `getRows()`, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it this way:

```
this.urlParamService.getParameterGroup(this.parameterPrefix)
    .distinctUntilChanged()
    .do(p => {
        this.tableLoad = this.getRows(p).subscribe((r) => this.rows = this.parseRows(r));
    })
    .subscribe();
```

So I stopped trying to use both Observable sequences as one (even though one depends on the other), and just subscribed to the second as a side effect of the first.